# Why doesn't the method "setMaximumSize" work although "setMinimumSize" does?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyClass {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

       myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
       myFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
       myFrame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

       myFrame.setVisible(true);
       myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }

}
```

Comment: @zigdon - I'm guessing he can make the frame smaller than 300, 300

Comment: Would be nice if we weren't trying to guess :)

Comment: @zigdon - it would be :)

Comment: @zigdon: He said: "Why doesn't the method `setMaximumSize` work" which means that he can make it bigger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6464548